# position sizing in TradingView pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I’m new in writing pinescript and I want to know about position sizing in pinescript. My system seem to have a little bit drawdown so I decide to deal with this problem by adjusting position size.

1.Can we customize our own money management strategy in pinescript?

2.Can we apply advance money management such as Kelly criterion and optimal f model into tradingview pinescript?

3.My idea about position size that I want to implement is like this example…

1.we have capital of 1000$
2.we define our risk per trade in percent. Let say 2%.
That’s mean we will loss 20$ if it wouldn’t  go on at we want.
3.We have a stop loss prepare in order to calculate the position size let’s say 2ATR from closing price

If the price is 10$ and stop loss level is 5$
We can buy 20$/(10$-5$) = 4 shares
Then we calculate back to our position size = 4*10 = 40$
Our position size is 40$

I want to implement this method to TradingView. Is it possible to do somethings like this? I also want to limit number of positon to no more than 3 positions in the same direction.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

> 1.Can we customize our own money management strategy in pinescript?

Yes, you can.

> 2.Can we apply advance money management such as Kelly criterion and optimal f model into tradingview pinescript?

Yes, you can. Pinescript has built-in variables like `strategy.closedtrades.entry_price`, `strategy.closedtrades.exit_price`, `strategy.closedtrades.profit`, `strategy.closedtrades.size` etc. which hold historical data (old trades) too. You can use those and some other variables to calculate the things you need for Kelly criterion and optimal f model.

> 1.we have capital of 1000$ 2.we define our risk per trade in percent. Let say 2%. That’s mean we will loss 20$ if it wouldn’t go on at we
> want. 3.We have a stop loss prepare in order to calculate the position
> size let’s say 2ATR from closing price
>
> If the price is 10$ and stop loss level is 5$ We can buy 20$/(10$-5$)
> = 4 shares Then we calculate back to our position size = 4*10 = 40$ Our position size is 40$

The `strategy.entry()` function has the following signature:

```
strategy.entry(id, direction, qty, limit, stop, oca_name, oca_type, comment, when, alert_message) → void
```

You can use the `qty` parameter for that.

> **qty** (series int/float) An optional parameter. Number of
> contracts/shares/lots/units to trade.

> I also want to limit number of positon to no more than 3 positions in
> the same direction

That's called `pyramiding` and it is possible.

> **pyramiding** (const int) The maximum number of entries allowed in the
> same direction